# File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 216, in _lock_unlock_module Error

Tags: django, django-models

I am hosting my Django site in C panel and I am getting the above error when I try to migrate the database to create tables and schema. What could be the issue?

I have never encountered such an error before. I did an online research on the problem and I am not able to get the solutions to the exact problem. In what circumstances do frozen importlib._bootstrap errors occur? Also, what could be the problem with my codebase to trigger the error?

Below is the full error log:

```
stderr:
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 23 of 24: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC -1 current, -1 max
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/albaalaw/public_html/family_tree_backend/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/albaalaw/public_html/family_tree_backend/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 416, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 602, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 595, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/opt/alt/python310/lib64/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/albaalaw/public_html/family_tree_backend/family_tree_backend/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('trees/', include('trees.urls')),
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/opt/alt/python310/lib64/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/albaalaw/public_html/family_tree_backend/trees/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/albaalaw/public_html/family_tree_backend/trees/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/home/albaalaw/virtualenv/public_html/family_tree_backend/3.10/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 216, in _lock_unlock_module
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue went away on its own after I reinstalled packages from requirements.txt and ran migrations. Still doesn't understand the source of the error